# MYSQL Random value between 1 and MAX value in Table

Tags: mysql, select, random

I need some help with a random variable in MySQL. I want it to pick a random value between 1 and the highest value in the table surnames. The solution eludes me..

```
 SET id = ROUND(RAND()*((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM surnames)-1)+1);                  
 SET surnameValue = (SELECT asurname FROM surnames WHERE surname_id = id);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you need one single value or a value for each row.  Therefore, I will show you both solutions.  I am also going to assume you want a random integer.

Now since I do not see the table I am going to label 'valueField' as the column that defines the max value.  The 'primaryKeyField' is the field in which you can join a table to itself.

Here is a solution if you want one single value...

```
SELECT (FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) * max(valueField) )) AS value
FROM surnames
```

Here is a solution if you want a value for each row you select...

```
SELECT (FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) * `max` )) AS value
FROM surnames s
INNER JOIN (SELECT primaryKeyField, max(valueField) as `max`
            FROM surnames 
            GROUP BY valueField) r ON r.primaryKeyField = s.primaryKeyField
```